# Applying a javascript to a table within a table

Tags: javascript, html, selector

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('td').click(function () {
        // statements 
    }
    });
</script>
```

that changes the background color of the cell when clicking on a td cell in a table. The problem is, I want to apply this to a table (`id=table2`) within a table (`id=table1`). What happens now is that it's applied to table1.

I tried using this selector: `$('#table2 td').click`... like I've seen in some forums/answers here, but it's not working for me.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: I'd understand the problem if `table2` was the parent of `table1`, not the other way around. Because your selector is targetting all tds that are hierarchically under `table2`, regardless of nesting depth.

Comment: post some mark up .. and let us know what exactly you want

Comment: put your HTML code also ...

Comment: can't you use `#table2 #table1 td` ??

Comment: try selector ' $('#table1 #table2 td').click '....

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this came from a copy paste or something, I tested this and saw "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } " in Chrome. You probably had a document ready chunk of code above the first line of jQuery.

So this is probably what you want just making your code example work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('td').click(function () {
    alert('test clicked')
})});
```

For your required solution, you can just use `$('#table2 td').click`, once you have valid javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBL2y/

Note: The console in Chrome (other browsers are available) is very helpful to catch these kind of problems as they show up as errors here.